# Prevent a function from creating a file

Tags: python

I'm using the `pywhatkit` library for sending whatsapp messages.
Whenever I call the function `pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly`, it automatically prints an output when finished, and adds some information including date, time, phone-number, message sent to a file called `pywhatkit_dbs.txt`.
I was able to prevent the function from printing an output to the stdout using this code:

```
class HiddenPrints:
    def __enter__(self):
        self._original_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        sys.stdout.close()
        sys.stdout = self._original_stdout
```

And calling the function like this:

```
with HiddenPrints():
    pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(...)
```

Now I want in the same way (by creating another class like `HiddenPrints`) to block the function from creating the log file `pywhatkit_dbs.txt`.
What should be the class, and how can I call the two classes (with `HiddenPrints`) using `with` when operating the function?

Comment: I think you should limit your question to one topic.

Comment: As an aside, don't reinvent the wheel, use the standard library `contextlib.redirect_stdout`, so `with contextlib.redirect_stdout(os.devnull): ...`

Comment: Since PyWhatKit seems to use a relative path to pywhatkit_dbs.txt, one idea would be to change the working directory to a temporary directory, then change it back after calling PyWhatKit. Or, you could fork pywhatkit and change all of the places where it writes to the log file: https://github.com/Ankit404butfound/PyWhatKit/search?q=PyWhatKit_DB

Comment: `with unittest.mock.patch('pywhatkit.core.log.log_message'):` should do the trick. You can also monkey-patch the function out manually or fork the project and change it to properly use the `logging` module.

Comment: `pywhatkit.core.log.log_message = lambda *args, **kwargs: None`

Answer (score 0):

its not the most elegant of solutions but you can just delete the file once it has been created

```
import os
import pywhatkit

sendwhats_image(receiver='receiver',
                img_path='img_path',
                caption='caption',
                tab_close=True)

os.remove('PyWhatKit_DB.txt')
```

if you are running the scripts on a network location and are getting the permission error then change the working dir to your local drive and delete it after you are done.

```
import os
import pywhatkit

os.chdir("c:\\tmp")

sendwhats_image(receiver='receiver',
                img_path='img_path',
                caption='caption',
                tab_close=True)

os.remove('PyWhatKit_DB.txt')
```